# SignalR hub js file corrupted (mono 3.0.3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to run may MVC 4 application under mono 3.0.3 on ubuntu linux. App itself is running good, but signalr isn't. The issue i see is that signalr/hub file is corrupted. The file content seems to be valid javascript except first and last lines of that file.
[image]

I'm using dev branch signalr to build signalr. This number changed when i compiled signalr in linux.

[image]

This is how last line of that file is looking. **Issue happens in MONO only**. Under IIS it works as expected.

Please advise.

P.S. I can compile dev branch only. Master branch isn't compilable on my machine (mono 3.0.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webserver isn't handling chunked encoding properly (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding). I'm not sure what you need to do to fix that.

Comment: Probably you are correct - i'm using nginx on ubuntu 12 and seems it's not supporting chunked encoding